# Stopping table locks for MYISAM tables

Tags: mysql, multithreading, myisam

I have a MYISAM table on which long-running SELECT statements are conducted. Do these statements cause locks on the tables that are being read? If so, how do you stop the locks from occurring?

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html:

> MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables,
>   permitting only one session to update those tables at a time. This
>   locking level makes these storage engines more suitable for read-only,
>   read-mostly, or single-user applications.

Does this also mean that `SELECT` statements create locks?

Comment: @joanalo No it isn't. `SELECT` posts a shared-read lock, `UPDATE` and friends post a write lock.

Comment: MyISAM isn't really the best choice these days, so if you can switch to InnoDB it's probably for the best. It's much easier to tune, supports MVCC, and has a journal, meaning it generally won't implode if your server crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do these [long-running SELECT] statements cause locks on the tables that are being read?

Yes. A MyISAM table cannot be updated while it is being read from. If there is a long-running read (i.e, SELECT) query on the table, any UPDATE or DELETE queries will have to wait until the read query is complete.

(INSERT queries are *sometimes* an exception. So long as there are no internal holes in the table structure, a writer may be allowed to insert a row at the end of a table without obtaining a lock. However, if any rows are ever updated or deleted, this may create holes, which will require INSERT queries to obtain a write lock as well.)

For more information on the internals, read up on [table-level locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-table-level-locking). But the short and the long of matters is, you probably shouldn't use MyISAM if concurrency is a concern.

Comment: Thanks! For long-running SELECT queries, is InnoDB recommended over MyISAM then? Does InnoDB also lock rows that are affected with long-running running SELECTs?

Comment: @user2181948 InnoDB is recommended over MyISAM for _all_ purposes. It doesn't use table-level locking at all, and has better overall performance in current versions of MySQL.